# Show that a sequence is convergent, proving that is Cauchy sequence

Tags: calculus, analysis, cauchy-sequences

Be $\{\ \overrightarrow{x_n} \}$ a sequence in $\mathbb R^k$. Suppose that $\|\overrightarrow{x}_{n+1}-\overrightarrow{x_n}\|\leq r\|\overrightarrow{x_n}-\overrightarrow{x}_{n-1}\|$ with $0\leq r<1$.

Show that the sequence $\{ \overrightarrow{x_n}\}$ is convergent.

*Hint:* prove that sequence $\{\ \overrightarrow{x_n} \}$ is a Cauchy sequence, using:
$$\|\overrightarrow{x_m}-\overrightarrow{x_n}\|\leq \|\overrightarrow{x_m}-\overrightarrow{x}_{m-1}\|+\|\overrightarrow{x}_{m-1}-\overrightarrow{x}_{m-2}\|+\cdots+\|\overrightarrow{x}_{n+1}-\overrightarrow{x_n}\|$$
And hypothesis of sequence (with $m>n$).

My solution:

$$\|\overrightarrow{x_m}-\overrightarrow{x_n}\|\leq \|\overrightarrow{x_m}-\overrightarrow{x}_{m-1}\|+\|\overrightarrow{x}_{m-1}-\overrightarrow{x}_{m-2}\|+\cdots+\|\overrightarrow{x}_{n+1}-\overrightarrow{x_n}\|$$

using hypotesis of recurrence

$$\|\overrightarrow{x_m}-\overrightarrow{x_n}\|\leq r\|\overrightarrow{x}_{m-1}-\overrightarrow{x}_{m-2}\|+r\|\overrightarrow{x}_{m-2}-\overrightarrow{x}_{m-3}\|+\cdots+r\|\overrightarrow{x}_{n+1}-\overrightarrow{x_n}\|$$

$$\|\overrightarrow{x_m}-\overrightarrow{x_n}\|\leq r+r^2\|\overrightarrow{x}_{m-2}-\overrightarrow{x}_{m-3}\|+r^2\|\overrightarrow{x}_{m-3}-\overrightarrow{x}_{m-4}\|+\cdots+r^2\|\overrightarrow{x}_{n+1}-\overrightarrow{x_n}\|$$

$$\|\overrightarrow{x_m}-\overrightarrow{x_n}\|\leq r(1+r+r^2+...+r^n)\|\overrightarrow{x}_{n+1}-\overrightarrow{x_n}\|$$

Where
$1+r+r^2+...+r^n\leq\frac{1}{1-r}$

So
$$\|\overrightarrow{x_m}-\overrightarrow{x_n}\|\leq r(\frac{1}{1-r})\|\overrightarrow{x}_{n+1}-\overrightarrow{x_n}\|$$

So

$$\|\overrightarrow{x_m}-\overrightarrow{x_n}\|<\epsilon$$

Comment: i try to use the hypotesis such that $||\overrightarrow{x_m}-\overrightarrow{x_n}||\leq r||\overrightarrow{x_m}-\overrightarrow{x}_{m-1}||+r||\overrightarrow{x}_{m-1}-\overrightarrow{x}_{m-2}||+...+r||\overrightarrow{x}_{n+1}-\overrightarrow{x_n}||$, but I'm not sure

Comment: Please include your attempt as part of the question, not a comment

Comment: Try some induction on the RHS.

Comment: Note that $1+r+r^2+...+r^n \le {1 \over 1-r}$.

Comment: Looks good! ${}$

Comment: ty, if something are wrong, I would appreciate the correction